# Save the collected data in database of Qualtrics by Javascript

Tags: javascript, save, qualtrics

Now I do a balloon risk task in Qualtrics, people will click to pump a balloon, and eventually, the balloon may or may not explode so that I can record the pumping times to measure people's risk-taking behavior.

Now my problem is that I set two variables "number_pumps" and "exploded"(both are an array) to record participants behavioral outcomes, but I do not know how to add these two variables into embedded data of Qualtrics.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
$("#goOn").click(function() {
$("form[name=f1]").submit();
var currentQuestionID = this.getQuestionInfo().QuestionID;
var resultEmbeddedName = currentQuestionID + "_result"  
var resultEmbeddedName = "result_" + currentQuestionID.substring(3);
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData(resultEmbeddedName, number_pumps);
});
});
```

I hope that by clicking on "goOn", I can save the data of "number_pumps" into qualtrics. But now it does not work. Does anyone know how to add embedded data of the variables?

Answer (score 0):

First, you aren't even getting to setEmbeddedData because $ in Qualtrics is Prototypejs, not jQuery. Your syntax is wrong for Prototypejs.  Replace  $ with jQuery.

Second, you can't dynamically create an embedded data field in JavaScript. You first have to create it in the survey flow.

Third, number_pumps is undefined in your example. Seems like you've left out a lot of code.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. "First, you aren't even getting to setEmbeddedData because $ in Qualtrics is Prototypejs, not jQuery. Your syntax is wrong for Prototypejs. Replace $ with jQuery." Actually I found that '$' can work in Qualtrics, I do not know why, but I introduced 'jquery-ui.js' into qualtrics, maybe this is the reason?

Comment: "Second, you can't dynamically create an embedded data field in JavaScript. You first have to create it in the survey flow."     Yes, you are right, I have created label variables in the survey flow for embedded data, and now I can save and check the data.

Comment: "Third, number_pumps is undefined in your example. Seems like you've left out a lot of code."  You are right, I am sorry for that I did not write the codes for creating variables about 'number_pumps' here, but actually I created it before.  Now my questions have been solved. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Now the problem has been solved. Actually we need to add labels for embedded-data variables in the survey flow, importantly the labels and the variables have the same name. Then we can see and save the embedded data.